# Present UIImagePickerController over everything

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uikit

I'm trying to present an image picker from `KLCPopup` and over this popup.

Now I have this structure:

Main view controller initialize a `KLCPopup` with custom view, which is initialized with `Nib` file and accompanied by it's personal `UIView` subclass.

From that subclass I handle button pressed and try to present `UIImagePickerController`.

Firstly, I tried to present picker on `rootViewController`, but it appers under the popup.

Then I tried to changed modalPresentationStyle of picker controller to `OverFullScreen`(which doesn't work), to `OverCurrentContext` and every other.

I also wrote this extension to `UIView` class:

```
extension UIView {
    func getViewController() -> UIViewController? {
        for (var v = superview; v != nil; v = v?.superview) {
            let nextResp = v?.nextResponder()

            if nextResp is UIViewController { return (nextResp as! UIViewController) }

        }

        return nil
    }
}
```

And tried to present `UIImagePickerController` on the result of this method but it either doesn't work or the method returns nil.

What else I could try? I don't want my popup to close or pass any reference which will make my design bad.

Comment: There are at [least](https://github.com/jmascia/KLCPopup/issues/39) two [issues](https://github.com/jmascia/KLCPopup/issues/25) on the repository regarding this.

Comment: but no solution. maybe I can fix something in source code?